# DB2/SQL : Iterate and update columns one by one of one table with values from other table

Tags: db2, mybatis, ibatis

I have a table structure for example,

Table T1,

### ID | PART | PRCODE |PRVENDOR | PREX1 | PREX2 | PREX3

10  -  A1  -  A11   - AV1  -    1  -    0   -   0

20  -  A2  -  A22  -  AV2  -    1  -   0  -     0

30  -     A3  -     A33  -     AV3  -     1  -     0  -     0

40  -     A4  -     A44  -     AV4  -     1  -     0  -     0

50  -     A5  -     A55  -     AV5  -     1  -     0  -     0

60  -     A4  -     A66  -     AV6  -     1  -     0  -     0

Table T2,

### ID | PART | PRCODE |PRVENDOR | PDEX1 | PDEX2 | PDEX3

10  -   A1  -   A11  -   AV1  -   10  -     20   -   30

20  -   A2  -   A22  -   AV2  -   100 -     200  -   300

30  -   A3  -   A33  -   AV3  -   11  -     22   -   33

40  -   A4  -   A44  -   AV4  -   1   -     2    -   3

Now, I want to write a update query to update the PREX1, PREX2, PREX3 columns of Table T1 with PDEX1,PDEX2,PDEX3 columns of Table T2 by checking the
(ID, PART, PRCODE) matching (Common) records in T1 and T2.

If update is fine, as a result I want to get Table T1 as below,

Table T1,

### ID | PART | PRCODE |PRVENDOR | PREX1 | PREX2 | PREX3

10   - A1  -  A11  -  AV1  -    10  -   20  -   30

20   - A2  -  A22  -  AV2  -    100  -  200  -  300

30   - A3  -  A33  -  AV3  -    11  -   22  -   33

40   - A4  -  A44  -  AV4  -    1  -     2  -    3

50   - A5  -  A55  -  AV5  -    1  -    0  -    0

60   - A4  -  A66  -  AV6  -    1  -    0  -    0

Tried below queries, but not working as expected.

```
update T1 a 
inner join T2 b on ( 
                 (a.ID=b.ID) AND (a.PART=b.PART)  (a.PRCODE=b.PRCODE) 
                   )
                        )
       set a.PREX1= b.PDEX1,
           a.PREX2 = b.PDEX2,
           a.PREX3 = b.PDEX3
       where  ( (a.ID=b.ID) AND (a.PART=b.PART)  (a.PRCODE=b.PRCODE) )


   Error message: Keyword Inner not expected. valid tokens SET.
```

Also tried updating individual columns by below query,

```
update T1
set T1.PREX1 = (select T2.PDEX1
  FROM T2, T1
  ( (T1.ID=T2.ID) AND 
    (T1.PART =T2.PART) AND
    (T1.PRCODE=T2.PRCODE) 
  ) where T1.ID=10;
```

wrong result: This query updates all the PREX1 Column records to same value which is not expected.

Let me know if i am missing any conditions.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: ...how does that second query even run?  From the look of it you should be getting multiple results back from the subquery, which should be throwing an error.  From the look of things you can't directly use joins like that in DB2, which should be why your first query fails.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, Agree with the comment and I corrected the second query. Trying to update one record, the entire table is updated. I was not sure how to use joins with update query. Let me know if you can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is by using `merge statement`

```
MERGE INTO T1
USING T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID and T1.PART = T2.PART  and T1.PRCODE = T2.PRCODE
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET    T1.PREX1=T2.PDEX1,
                                T1.PREX2=T2.PDEX2,
                                T1.PREX3=T2.PDEX3;
```

or use can update with subquery

```
Update T1
Set PREX1 =(Select MAX(PDEX1)
 from T2
 Where T1.ID = T2.ID
   and T1.PART = T2.PART
   and T1.PRCODE = T2.PRCODE
 ),
 PREX2 =(Select MAX(PDEX2)
 from T2
 Where T1.ID = T2.ID
   and T1.PART = T2.PART
   and T1.PRCODE = T2.PRCODE
 ),
  PREX3 =(Select MAX(PDEX3)
 from T2
 Where T1.ID = T2.ID
   and T1.PART = T2.PART
   and T1.PRCODE = T2.PRCODE
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run:

```
Update T1
Set PREX1 =
(Select PDEX1
 from T2
 Where T1.ID = T2.ID
   and T1.PART = T2.PART
   and T1.PRCODE = T2.PRCODE
 );
```